# What does this sentence mean: "Troubles are poor things to hug. They've got too many prickers."

Tags: meaning, sentence

This is a sentence from a book for children. I'm trying to translate it into Chinese. Not sure what this means. DO we want to hug troubles or not?

Comment: I suppose there are people who would "hug" or, in other words, hold onto their troubles rather than face the hard task of dealing with the troubles and work to eliminate them.

Comment: @SarahHsu -- you might consider the word *hug* in the context of the phrase *[tree hugger](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tree_hugger)* and then replace the image of a tree with that of a plant with a lot prickers, like a [saguaro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saguaro).

Answer (score 2):

In this case, *[poor: 4a](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poor)* means "*inferior in quality or value*" or, another way of saying it is: **bad** because they have too many *thorns* (*[prickers](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prickers)*), which pierce the skin and cause pain.

Therefore, **no, we don't want to hug** ([embrace](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/embrace)) **troubles**.

Answer (score 1):

An illustration for *prickers*

[image: prickers]

Something you would not want to hug, because it has too many prickers.

Comment: Sometimes the "written language" of Bradbury's _Fahrenheit 451_ is much more effective than words.